# Attempt to de-reference a null object in rest test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, rest

I'm writting a test class for a rest class, and I'm getting a

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

and

> Class.RESTCommande.getCodeCommande: line 28, column 1
>   Class.RESTCommandeTest.getCodeCommande_Test: line 48, column 1

with which I remain blocked.

Here is a part of my Rest class :

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/comm')
global with sharing class RESTCommande  {

@HttpGet
global static String getCodeCommande() {
    String retour;
    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
    String eventId = req.params.get('eventId');
    Event comm;

    RecordType rtWeb = [SELECT Id
                                FROM RecordType
                                WHERE Name = 'Web'
                                AND SobjectType = 'Commande__c'
                                LIMIT 1];

    if(eventId == null){
        try {
            insert new Commande__c( Cons__c = comm.WhatId, RecordTypeId = rtWeb.Id);
        } catch (DMLException e) {
            return null;
        }

    }
    else{
      //some code
    }
  }
```

the line 28 is the one with `insert new Commande__c( Conseill_re__c = commandeWeb.WhatId, RecordTypeId = rtWeb.Id);`

My test class :

```
@isTest
private class RESTCommandeTest {

@isTest static void getCodeCommande_Test() {
    Account c= new Account(FirstName = 'test',
                                      LastName = 'test');
    insert c;
    Contact h= new Contact(Firstname = 'test',Lastname = 'test', Salutation = 'Madame');
    insert h;
    Event ev = new Event(StartDateTime = DateTime.now(),
                         EndDateTime = DateTime.now(),
                         Subject = 'Appel',
                         WhoId = h.Id,
                         WhatId = c.Id);
    insert ev;


    RestRequest req = new RestRequest();
    req.requestURI = 'https://cs86.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/comm?eventId=' + ev.Id;  
    req.httpMethod = 'GET';

    RestContext.request = req;

    RecordType rt= [SELECT Id
                                FROM RecordType
                                WHERE Name = 'Autre type'
                                AND SobjectType = 'Commande__c'
                                LIMIT 1];
    Commande__c comm = new Commande__c(H__c = h.Id,
                                        RecordTypeId = rt.Id,
                                        Cons__c = c.Id);
    String code = RESTCommande.getCodeCommande();

}


}
```

the error appear at the line with : `String code = RESTCommande.getCodeCommande();`

Comment: in ur insert statement, you are using Cons__c = comm.WhatId but you have not initialised or assigned anything to the variable comm. you just declared it and using it directly which is causing the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the reason of null pointer exception. Your event variable

```
Event comm;  // Can be initilized as Event comm=new Event ();
```

is not initialized in main code class. So you are not allowed to write a code line similar to one

```
 insert new Commande__c( Cons__c = comm.WhatId, RecordTypeId = rtWeb.Id);
```

because you can not refer whatid of a null variable.

The reason exception line was reached is because you were not able to set Event in RestRequest that resulted `eventId` to be null and finally reaching exception code.